# R Redo iteration for loop

Tags: r, control-flow

Is there a way in R to reiterate a for loop for a given count if a certain condition is true?

This is what I'm trying right now

```
for(i in 1:4){
  if(i == 4){
    i <- i-1
  }else{print(i)}
}
```

In this case I would want the output to be

```
[1] 1
[2] 2
[3] 3
[4] 3
[5] 3
[6] 3
...
```

Comment: You want an endless loop?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Technically yes, but I'll be randomly altering `i` in the for loop so it'll end eventually.

Comment: I'm not sure how are you going to do this "randomly", but the easiest way would be to convert this loop to a `while` loop <caution>

Comment: its not like other languages where you can change the iterator.  The C loop is creates its own variable that goes along the length of the sequence, and it is untouchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a while loop instead:

```
i <- 1

while(i <= 4){
  if(i == 4){
    i <- i-1
  }else{
    print(i)
    i <- i + 1
  }
}
```

But be aware that this is an infinite loop now...